# using a colon in a string in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i am using python 2.6.5 to develop an app for google app engine - i am not too familiar with python, but i'm learning.

i am trying to put a url into a string so variable = "string http://domain.name"

then i print the string out. the problem is, if the colon (after http) is in the string, i don't get any output and i don't know why.

i've tried escaping the string with:

- """http://domain.name"""
- r"http://domain.name"
- "http\://domain.name"
- "http\://domain.name"
- "http\\://domain.name"
- "http:://domain.name"

none of them seem to work and i'm not sure what else to try

The context is like so

variables.py is:

```
...
HOST_URL = "http://domain.name"
...
```

example logout.py

```
import variables
import sys

...

class Logout(webapp.RequestHandler):
    """ RequestHandler for when a user wishes to logout from the system."""
    def post(self):
        self.get()

    def get(self):
        print(variables.HOST_URL)
        print('hi')
        self.redirect(variables.HOST_URL)
        sys.exit()
```

or

in file functions.py

```
import variables
import sys

...

def sendhome(requesthandler)
    print 'go to '+variables.HOST_URL
    requesthandler.redirect(variables.HOST_URL)
    sys.exit()
```

called from a context like:

```
from functions import sendhome

...

class Logout(webapp.RequestHandler):
    """ RequestHandler for when a user wishes to logout from the system."""
    def post(self):
        self.get()

    def get(self):
        sendhome(self)
```

any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Are you saying that 'print "http://domain.name"' does not print out that whole string? That seems highly unlikely.

Comment: it didn't until i removed sys.exit() from underneath. i don't know why that prevented the printing of just the url and not the hi, but it did.

Comment: You might want to consider using python 2.5 as well - though unrelated to your problem, it is a good practice because the [GAE runtime uses python 2.5.2](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not terrible mistaken, GAE uses WSGI, you do not simply print things, you are supposed to return a proper HTTP response object (it is not PHP).

I guess that if you access the page using firefox+firebug and look at the network->header you will see that the browser is taking http: as an HTTP header with value "//domain.name".

Edited: By the way, should not you be using "self.response.out.write" instead of "print"?

Comment: it was in the context you asked for. the sys.exit()

Comment: google.appengine.ext.webapp.WSGIApplication is way better than CGI.

Comment: so i assume the headers that i have set using the webapp.RequestHandler are not sent if i call sys.exit() is there any way i can get around that? basically i want to prevent any further execution if a redirect occurs

Comment: return will get you out of the function or method call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the sys.exit() after the call to print or redirect